# Monotone & bounded of an integral function .

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

Let , $f: [0,1]\to \mathbb R$ be such that $f(t)\ge 0$ for all $t\in [0,1]$. Define , $$g(x)=\int_0^xf(t) \,dt.$$ Then

(A) $g$ is monotone & bounded

(B) $g$ is monotone but not bounded

(C) $g$ is bounded but not monotone

(D0 $g$ is neither monotone nor bounded

My Thought : If $f$ is continuous then $g'(x)\ge 0$ then $g$ is monotone increasing & also bounded as, $f$ is bounded..But, here $f$ is not continuous..So we can not differentiate $g$..So how we can proceed ?

Comment: $f$ is Riemann integrable or just measurable?

Comment: Riemann integrable...So $f$ is bounded..and then $g$ is bounded...But what about monotone ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boundedness has been addressed. Monotonicity: let $x<y$. In particular $y=x+s$ for some $s>0$. Then $$g(y)=\int_0^y f(t)dt=\int_0^{x+s} f(t)dt=\int_0^x f(t)dt+\int_x^{x+s}f(t)dt\geq \int_0^x f(t)dt=g(x)$$
Here we use $\int_x^{x+s}f(t)dt\geq0$ since $f(t)\geq 0$. This is a standard proposition for Riemann integrable functions.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $g(x)-g(y)$ where $x>y$.

Edit, if $f(t)$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$ then $g(x)$ is bounded.

Comment: If I may, if $f(t)$ is Riemann integrable, why can we say $g(x)$ is bounded?

Comment: $f$ is R. integrable implies $f$ is bounded & then $g$ is bounded...but monotone is NOT clear to me

Comment: It's the definition of the Riemann integral. $f$ is bounded on $[0,1]$, so for any partition the upper sums and lower sums must be finite, so the supremum/inf is always finite. There's a bound on how large the max and mins of $f$ can be.

Comment: As I said for monotone, consider $g(x)-g(y)$. Remember that the integral of a positive function is positive.